# Displaying Standard fields labels in vf page

Tags: visualforce, label, standard-field

Can we display standard fields labels in vf page by using

```
<apex:column headervalue="{!$ObjectType.ABC__c.Fields.CreatedBy.Label}"> ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field API for `CreatedBy` is `CreatedById` so try this:-

`<apex:column headervalue="{!$ObjectType.ABC__c.Fields.CreatedById.Label}">`

Answer (score 0):

That particular standard field does not work as answered in [Referencing the localized label for the standard CreatedBy relationship (localized version of "Created By")](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8973/referencing-the-localized-label-for-the-standard-createdby-relationship-localiz). But, for example, the standard `Name` field does work.

So the answer is "sometimes".